# Gray disabled button with custom background in Android

Tags: android

How to gray out button with custom background when it is in disabled state ?

Comment: closed as not a real question ?

Not real question but real answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me a little time so here is a solution I came up with.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_enabled="false”>
    <layer-list>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/button"/>
        <item>
            <color android:color="#88FFFFFF" />
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button" android:state_pressed="false"/>

</selector>
```

Basically you have to use layer-list in one of button states and layer transparent color over your background...

Comment: I had to also add `android:state_enabled="true"` to the default state in order for this to work.